# python argsparse data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am running into a weird problem with args.parse in python 3.4 and I need some help. I am just starting with python, so it may be something stupid.

I am passing an argument

```
parser.add_argument('-solr', type=str, default='http://localhost:8983/solr/', nargs='+', help='Address of Solr server (ex: http://192.168.137.128:8983/solr/)')
```

It should be just one argument, all the time. If I actually pass the argument, it will get stored as an array and I will need to access it via args.solr[0]. However, if I don't pass any arguments to it, the default value will be used, but it will be stored as string, thus, args.solr[0] will be 'h'.

What gives? I've tried to play around with nargs, but even setting it to 1 doesn't seem to change anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your argument is flagged (name starts with `-`) you don't need to set `nargs` at all - use its default `None`.  It is optional (not required) unless you use the flag string.

```
parser.add_argument('--solr', default='http://localhost:8983/solr/', 
    help='Address of Solr server (ex: %(default)s)')
```

With this, sample inputs produce:

```
In [51]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[51]: Namespace(solr='http://localhost:8983/solr/')

In [52]: parser.parse_args(['--solr','test'])
Out[52]: Namespace(solr='test')

In [50]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython [-h] [--solr SOLR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --solr SOLR  Address of Solr server (ex: http://localhost:8983/solr/)
```

With longer optional names, a `--` is better than `-`.  The default type is `str`, so you don't need to specify that.  I've added `%(default)s` to the help, so you don't have to repeat the default value.

If you do want the result to be a list, e.g. `['test']`, use `nargs=1` and put the default in a list as well, e.g. `default=['http...']`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nargs = '?'`. It stopped taking the input as an array.

`parser.add_argument('--solr', type=str, default='http://localhost:8983/solr/',nargs='?',help='Address of Solr server (ex: http://192.168.137.128:8983/solr/)')`

Comment: `nargs='?'` is more useful on positionals than optionals - unless you want `--solr` without any argument to mean something.